# SharePoint 2016 Ribbon Custom Theme

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ribbon, custom, theme

Is there a way to change the colour of the top black default ribbon of SharePoint?

Comment: Use this link that mey be helpfull to know about custom themes https://johnmhester.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/changing-the-top-bar-color-in-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It changes with the theme under site setting "Look and Feel" settings. If you want to change only banner you write css in the master page or common css file.

`.o365cs-base.o365cs-topnavBGColor-2,
.o365cs-base .o365cs-topnavLinkBackground-2 {
    background-color: grey;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I found a very useful tool for this purpose. It's called SharePoint Color Palette Tool. If someone wants to make custom theme for the ribbon I suggest to use this tool. It's easy and fast.